# Silverlight exception not being handled with JS

Tags: javascript, silverlight-2.0

I am debugging Silverlight 2 on Firefox. I get an unhandled error in firebug:

> ```
> Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application
> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.GetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper obj, DependencyProperty property)
> at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isSetByStyle, Boolean isSetByBuiltInStyle, PropertyInvalidationReason reason)
> at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
> at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
> at System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)
> at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp, Binding binding)
> at FileAudit.Page..ctor()
> at FileAudit.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
> at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
> ```

points to Silverlight.js line 26 which is

```
control = new ActiveXObject('AgControl.AgControl');
```

my html is

```
<head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Silverlight.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {

        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
            appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }
        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        var errMsg = "Unhandled j Error in Silverlight 2 Application " + appSource + "\n";

        errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        $("#errorLocation").html(errMsg);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Runtime errors from Silverlight will be displayed here.
    This will contain debugging information and should be removed or hidden when debugging is completed -->
    <div id="silverlightControlHost2">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
            width="431" height="30" id="Xaml2">
            <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/FileAudit.xap" />
            <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="2.0.31005.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
            <param name="initParams" value="id=slPlugin1,embeddingTechnique=objectElement" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                    style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
        <iframe style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id='errorLocation' style="font-size: small; color: Gray;">
    </div>

</body>
```

Why is it not getting handled in JS and being displayed in errorLocation?
Also sorry my formatting sucks.

Comment: Does it work in IE and/or when you run from Visual Studio or Blend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with a solution
Went to the App.xaml.cs file and reworked the Unhandled_Exception Function

With that and a bit of call this JS it was easy

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the app is running outside of the debugger then report the exception using
        // the browser's exception mechanism. On IE this will display it a yellow alert 
        // icon in the status bar and Firefox will display a script error.


        // NOTE: This will allow the application to continue running after an exception has been thrown
        // but not handled. 
        // For production applications this error handling should be replaced with something that will 
        // report the error to the website and stop the application.
        e.Handled = true;

        try
        {
            ThrowRightError(e.ExceptionObject);
            //System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight  a 2 Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
    private void ReportErrorToDOM(ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ThrowRightError(e.ExceptionObject);
            //System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private void ThrowRightError(Exception e)
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        var exLayer = -1;
        //errorMsg += String.Format("<br>Layer {0}<hr>", exLayer);
        Exception ex2 = e;
        while (ex2 != null)
        {
            errorMsg += "Message : <br />" + ex2.Message + "<br />Data :<br />" + ex2.Data + "<br />StackTrace :<br />" + ex2.StackTrace;
            exLayer++;
            errorMsg += String.Format("<br>Layer {0}<hr>", exLayer);
            ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
        }
        errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"<br />");

        HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("foo2", new[] { errorMsg });
    }
```

then for the JS

```
function foo2(theAlert) {
     $("#errorLocation").html(theAlert);
}
```

I also figured out what the original error was

```
ClientIdTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, ClientIdBinding);
```

A textBox binding for a Text*Block*...stupid mistake.